In the Wallace and Gromit movies we see 'Electronics for Dogs.' Do we ever see any other 'books for Dogs' in-universe?
In more than one of the comedy animated movies about Wallace and Gromit we see the in universe book "Electronics for Dogs". Sometimes only on a bookcase.

This is obviously a play on the real-world "____ for Dummies" series of reference books.It also establishes that, although Gromit cannot speak, he can read English and understand an electronics book.
Do we ever see any other books entitled "____ for Dogs"?

We don't see any other "____ for Dogs" books, but Gromit can be seen reading a number of canine-themed titles throughout the various films.
This includes;

The Republic - The author is listed as Pluto (likely a reference to the canine pal of Mickey Mouse). It's a reference to the short book Republic by the Greek philosopher Plato.
Crime and Punishment by Fido Dogstoyevsky. The author's name is a play on Fyodor Dostoevsky, who wrote the actual book.
Men are from Mars, Dogs are from Pluto - No author is listed, but the title is a play on the title of the famous relationship book Men are from Mars, Women are from Venus.

His kennel also contains some less punny titles; 'Kennels', 'Sheep II', 'Bones', and 'Poodles'.




The "A Penguin Classic" spine also seems to be a joke/reference to Feathers McGraw from The Wrong Trousers.

@MiloP The penguin illustration, I suppose yeah... but it's worth noting that Penguin Classics are a real book line, and they look pretty much like that. (Just with a smaller penguin-illustration logo.) "A Penguin Classic" itself isn't any kind of joke/pun.

@FeRD Sure, yeah, I just meant it seems like they'd only make the publisher legible on the prop and add the W&G-style penguin if they were going for the joke. Always possible that Penguin's been getting into the lucrative stop-motion product placement market, though!

@MiloP - Penguin have been publishing Wallace and Gromit books for years. I doubt they had to pay them to use the logo. It's just an in-joke; https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wallace-Gromit-Publisher-Character-Paperback/dp/B00SLUQEMO / https://wallaceandgromit.fandom.com/wiki/Wallace_%26_Gromit_Activity_Book
